# NativeAPI Suspend process

Tags: c, process, masm, nt-native-api

I try to stop some process, I use NativeAPI from ntdll. I wrote some C code, It works:

```
typedef LONG(NTAPI* NtSuspendProcess)(IN HANDLE ProcessHandle);

UINT __stdcall Suspend(VOID* processId)
{
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, (DWORD)processId);

    NtSuspendProcess pfnNtSuspendProcess = (NtSuspendProcess)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "NtSuspendProcess");

    pfnNtSuspendProcess(processHandle);

    CloseHandle(processHandle);

    return 0;
}

UINT __stdcall Resume(VOID* processId)
{
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, (DWORD)processId);

    NtSuspendProcess pfnNtSuspendProcess = (NtSuspendProcess)GetProcAddress(
    GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "NtResumeProcess");

    pfnNtSuspendProcess(processHandle);

    CloseHandle(processHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

But, when I try to write it using MASM, my process doesn't stop. I looked registers EAX and ECX, everything is okay there. I called GetLastError, there was zero, as return value. Code:

```
pauseProc proc pid:dword

push pid
push 0
push PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
call OpenProcess@12

.IF eax == 0
    PUSH MB_ICONERROR
    PUSH 0
    PUSH offset errorOpenProccess
    PUSH 0
    CALL MessageBoxA@16 
.ENDIF

mov processHandle, eax

push offset NtModuleNameWStr
call GetModuleHandleW@4

; call GetLastError

.IF eax == 0
    PUSH MB_ICONERROR
    PUSH 0
    PUSH offset errorGetModuleHandle
    PUSH 0
    CALL MessageBoxA@16 
.ENDIF

push offset NtSuspendProcessAStr
push eax
call GetProcAddress@8

.IF eax == 0
    PUSH MB_ICONERROR
    PUSH 0
    PUSH offset errorGetProcAddress
    PUSH 0
    CALL MessageBoxA@16 
.ENDIF

push processHandle
call CloseHandle@4

; pfnNtSuspendProcess
ret
pauseProc endp
```

About consts:

```
STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED equ 000F0000h
SYNCHRONIZE              equ 00100000h
PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS      equ (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED or SYNCHRONIZE or 0FFFFh)
```

I use Windows 10, because we need write 0FFFF. For versions before Windows Vista 0FFFh. Why process doesn't stop?

Comment: Have you viewed/compared the assembly code of the executable from the code you wrote against the MASM code to see what significant differences there are?

Comment: Yes, I did it. There were some functions j___RTC_CheckEsp, which check something. I even tried to call __imp__OpenProcess@12 and etc. Btw, when I call this GetModuleHandle it'll be replace by __imp__GetModuleHandleW@4.

Comment: it function has W post-fix, this suggest that I use Unicode, I've changed some variables. Since, GetProcAddress requiers ASCII characters. Once, my process stoped, but I don't know why

Comment: I have almost the same code, but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think `.IF` does what you think it does.

Comment: About OpenProcess: If the function fails, the return value is NULL. If I'll be get NULL from OpenProcess, then in EAX will be 0x00000000. I'm right?

Comment: @user253751 The use of `.IF` looks reasonable to me. MASM has both `.IF` and `IF`. The former is for runtime conditions, and the latter is for build-time conditions.

Comment: As far as I can tell you're never calling the address returned by `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Ah, Yes... But I have a difficult construction in my c code. I realized, but how can I write it by MASM. Because, there is function pointer (in c code), how can I use MASM for this operation?

Comment: If I'll do that `g_pFunction dd offset SomeFunction00`, can I call g_pFunction?
Is it correct note? Or should I use `jmp dword [var]`?

Comment: My EAX register will be contain some function address?

Comment: Why not just `push processHandle` / `call eax` ?

Comment: Can I do that? May I call some register?
Turns out that, when I call some function, I just call `call 0x0003ABC4`?

Comment: Sure you can. Also, download _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B and 3C_.

Comment: It's working, I call eax after last function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;Process pause
pauseProc proc pid:dword

push pid
push 0
push PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
call OpenProcess@12

.IF eax == 0
    PUSH MB_ICONERROR
    PUSH 0
    PUSH offset errorOpenProccess
    PUSH 0
    CALL MessageBoxA@16 
.ENDIF

mov processHandle, eax

push offset NtModuleNameWStr
call GetModuleHandleW@4

; call GetLastError

.IF eax == 0
    PUSH MB_ICONERROR
    PUSH 0
    PUSH offset errorGetModuleHandle
    PUSH 0
    CALL MessageBoxA@16 
.ENDIF

push offset NtSuspendProcessAStr
push eax
call GetProcAddress@8

.IF eax == 0
    PUSH MB_ICONERROR
    PUSH 0
    PUSH offset errorGetProcAddress
    PUSH 0
    CALL MessageBoxA@16 
.ENDIF

;Call NtSuspendProcess from dll
push processHandle
call eax

push processHandle
call CloseHandle@4

; pfnNtSuspendProcess
ret
pauseProc endp
```